# Classifying a metachar in a antlr4 grammar

Tags: parsing, syntax, antlr4, grammar

I am writing up a document to describe a basic regular expression parser that I've written, and I'm a bit unclear on what exactly constitutes a "meta-character". For example, of the following three items:

```
$
\d
[a-z]
```

What is the definition of a 'meta-character' (not an escape sequence), and how would the above be classified properly?

Comment: In normal usage, `$`, backslash, and `]` are metacharacters; in other words, they are not simple literal pattern characters and would need to be escaped to be used as pattern characters. Others include `.`, `*`, `+`, parentheses and braces. `\d` is an escape sequence representing a character class; `[a-z]` is a character class.

Comment: But there's no formal definition of "metacharacter", outside of specific domains. And even if there were, not everyone would respect it. So don't get too hung up about it, and if you think it's important to use that word, provide your own definition.